Lengths of binary Huffman codes for uniform distribution
A binary Huffman code for a pmf $(p_1,\dots,p_m)$ is constructed by starting with all $p_i$ as leaves and iteratively constructing a tree by merging the two nodes of lowest probability. Edges are then given labels in $\{0,1\}$, and we read off codewords by the root-leaf paths.
Suppose we carry out this procedure for the uniform distribution on $\{1,\dots,100\}$, how many codewords are there of each length?
The solution to this exercise was given simply as: "by the Huffman construction, there are 28 codewords of length 6 and 72 of length 7". I can see we'll end up with almost a complete binary tree, so we'll get lengths on either side of $\log_{2}(100)\approx6.6$, but I'm struggling to run through the algorithm and get exact numbers here.

No need to run through the algorithm if all the probabilities are equal. At 100 characters, there are 28 too few for $2^7$ or 36 too many for $2^6,$ meaning that 28 of the leaves will have depth 6, and $36.2=72$ of them have depth 7. If the number of characters had been odd, there would have been one intermediate node at depth 6 with only one child.
